# How do i hash the values inside a byte array using MD5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, md5, nsdata

i have a NSData value ,i find the bytes of that value by using following code

```
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(24); //byte array
    int len=[result length];   //find the length
    memcpy(byteData, [result bytes], len); // copy the bytes values of "result" to bytes array

    NSString *MD5Key=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[result md5]]; // find md5 values
    NSLog(@"%@",MD5Key);
    NSString *finalKey=[MD5Key substringToIndex:8];
```

but i need the MD5 value of that byte array (byteData)? how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this method and hope you can change it for your goal.

```
- (NSString *) md5_forString: (NSString*) sourceString
{
    const char *cStr = [sourceString UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[16];
    CC_MD5( cStr, (unsigned int) strlen(cStr), result);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
            result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
            result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
            result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
            result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
            ];      
}
```